# How to make a user control that binds different types?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to make a UserControl in which a user could bind more than one type of data. Usually I define a dependency property, for example:

```cs
  public ObservableCollection<MyDataType1> Values
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyDataType1>)GetValue(ValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValuesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Values", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyDataType1>),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                null));
```

**How can I define a cast from some type to MyDataType1?**

Example:

```
public class MyDataType1
{
     string ID { get; set; }
     string Title { get; set; }
     SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like that is possible to bind also:

```
ObservableCollection<int> TestCollection { get; set; }
```

I tried to define in MyDataType1 an implicit cast:

```
static public implicit operator MyDataType1(int value)
    {
        return new MyDataType1()
        {
           ID = value,
           Color = Colors.Black,
           Title = "Not defined"
        };
    }
```

However, when I bind the collection with ints, my control doesn't show anything.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
```

To achieve this I *don't* want to define a `Converter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings to object properties get resolved at **Runtime**, this means you can pretty much dump any binding in the XAML and if the binding doesn't work, it'll just ignore it.

Using this, it's possible to effectively *pick and choose* what data type you're going to use. I would say the best method of achieving this is to make use of an `interface`. Here's an example:

```
public interface IAwesome
{
    int ID { get; }
}

public class MegaClass : IAwesome
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SuperClass : IAwesome
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Using this method, your dependency property will look something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<IAwesome> Values
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<IAwesome>)GetValue(ValuesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValuesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Values", typeof(ObservableCollection<IAwesome>),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            null));
```

Another thing to mention is that you can also make use of a typed `DataTemplate`, see here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNamespace:SomethingOrOther}">
```

This will allow you to define a `DataTemplate` for a specific `Type`, so even though your collection is a list of `IAwesome`, they may be displayed differently in the container based on their assigned `DataTemplate`.

The beauty of this is that your strongly typed C# will still be valid, however in your scenario, we need to make this even *more* generic.

The method of using an `interface` doesn't really solve your problem, because `int` can't inherit from `IAwesome`, so you're going to get compiler errors if you try to assign any `int` values to this property. A way to get around this is to instead use `object`.

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Values
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ValuesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValuesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Values", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>),
        typeof(MyUserControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            null));
```

Because **everything** inherits from `object`, you can add **any** value to this collection.

This is all fine and dandy until you actually need to make use of this property in C#. You're going to have lots of headaches because you will need to **cast** these objects to their desired types.

In the scenario where you don't need to use these values, then this should suffice, otherwise, perhaps you need to re-think your control, perhaps it's trying to do **too many things**.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection is not a good idea. Try accessing a property that attempts to return the value fetched from the dependency property (say that at runtime you bound ObservableCollection to it) with a cast to ObservableCollection. It will bomb. This is because your custom data types are not inheriting from object. It violates a rule known as "covariance". I tried this approach and hit a dead end. Interfaces is the only way to go. Maybe dynamic objects.